# Dynamic datasources and global in Cakephp 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, connection, cakephp-3.0

I have an application that will be used by many databases. To choose the database with the application data I have a database with the connections parameters (host, username, pass, database...)

The problem is that this dynamically created datasource does not work for the rest of the application.

**Controller Code**

```
$data       = $this->request->data;
$connection = ConnectionManager::get("default");
$query      = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id = ".$data['codigo'];
$result     = $connection->execute($query)->fetchAll('assoc');

ConnectionManager::drop('default');            

$config = ConnectionManager::config('connection', [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => $result[0]['host'],
        'username' => $result[0]['username'],
        'password' => $result[0]['password'],
        'database' => $result[0]['database'],
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ]);

$connection = ConnectionManager::get('connection');
ConnectionManager::alias('connection', 'default');

return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Mains', 'action' => 'index']);
```

After this redirect, apparently the other controllers do not have this datasource.

Comment: Ouch, that's an SQL injection vulnerability right there! Never every directly insert user data into queries!

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly a bit unusual to be swapping databases based on contents inside request data - but generally database connection just needs to be done earlier on in Cake's initial setup, as each Controller's connection resource is already set to the `default`.

If you're only swapping the one time, you could manage this inside `config/bootstrap.php` (where Cake normally sets up it's ConnectionManager) instead.

You won't have access to `$this->request`, but could just grab it from $_REQUEST instead, for example:

In `config/bootstrap.php`, change these lines:

```
Cache::config(Configure::consume('Cache'));
ConnectionManager::config(Configure::consume('Datasources'));
Email::configTransport(Configure::consume('EmailTransport'));
```

To this:

```
Cache::config(Configure::consume('Cache'));

ConnectionManager::config(Configure::consume('Datasources'));
$connection = ConnectionManager::get("default");
$client = TableRegistry::get('Clients')->find()
    ->where(['client_id'=> $_REQUEST['client_id']])->firstOrFail();

ConnectionManager::drop('default');

$config = ConnectionManager::config('connection', [
    'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
    'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => $client->host,
    'username' => $client->username,
    'password' => $client->password,
    'database' => $client->database,
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'flags' => [],
    'cacheMetadata' => true,
    'log' => false,
    'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
]);

ConnectionManager::get('connection');

Email::configTransport(Configure::consume('EmailTransport'));
```

**Edited:** Switched from your raw SQL to a Table::find()

Comment: You've inherited the OPs SQL injection vulnerability!

Comment: I changed the code and this error appeared: **Notice (8): Undefined index: codigo [ROOT\config\bootstrap.php, line 156]**. I need to get this data through a form before doing the configuration. The cakephp read the bootstrap.php before my form.

Comment: Ah - what database should it be connecting to when it's first rendering that form? The default? If so, just wrap everything after `ConnectionManager::config(Configure::consume('Datasources'));` in a big if statement (`if(!empty($_REQUEST['codigo']){`), up until that Email line

Comment: Man, did not work. I forgot to delete the direct connection to one of the database that has the base connections